# Question about the matrix representation of the differentiation map on the subspace generated by $\{1, t, e^{t}, e^{2t}\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, vector-spaces, problem-solving

As mentioned in a previous post (I think), I've been trying to learn some linear algebra, and so I've begun to post little questions whose answers I'm sure are obvious to most here; this is just a way for me to clarify my thinking and reassure myself that I am on the right track/get myself back, as it were, on the right track.

Let $D = \partial /\partial t$ be the differentiation map on the space $V$ of smooth functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.  Let $U$ be the subspace generated by the set $\{1, t, e^{t}, e^{2t}\}$.  I am trying to find the matrix associated to $D \big |_U$ (restricting $D$ to $U$) relative to the ordered basis $\{1, t, e^{t}, e^{2t}\}$.  I am pretty sure that this matrix should be

\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}

considering the derivatives of each basis vector.  However, I was wondering if the matrix

\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1/t & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}

might also be an alternative candidate.

Comment: @HenningMakholm:  Oops...thanks for pointing that out - corrected now.

Comment: @Dang, sorry for writing over your comment - I meant to respond to it!  Shows you what an amateur I am.

Comment: You didn't overwrite it -- I just happened to delete mine while you were typing, since it was not relevant anymore.

Comment: Whew...okay, that's good!  Anyhow, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Good question, by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your alternative doesn't work because the matrix should not depend on $t$.

At least, as long as you view the function space as a *real* vector space the matrix elements have to be members of $\mathbb R$. Your $1/t$ is (at best) a *function* rather than a real number, and therefore does not belong as a matrix element.

If you want to be all fancy about it, you *could* view your vector space as one over a larger scalar field than $\mathbb R$, for example the field of rational functions in $t$. If you do that, you'll be allowed to write $1/t$ as a matrix element -- but on the other hand your basis is then not a basis anymore, because $1$ and $t$ are linearly dependent when $t$ is just a scalar. And differentiation is then not a *linear* map anymore, so suddenly *no* matrix will work to represent it.

Comment: This is a wonderful answer!  Thanks!  When you say that "your basis is then not a basis anymore" do you say this because there'd be two ways (i.e., the two matrices proposed) to write out $D \big |_U$?

Comment: @user102851: If your assumed basis vectors are $\{f_1, f_2, f_3, f_4\}$, where $f_1(t)=1$ and $f_2(t)=t$, then they are linearly dependent, because $1\cdot f_1 + (-1/t)\cdot f_2 = 0$. (Remember this is under the assumption that $1/t$ now counts as a scalar). And by definition a linearly dependent set cannot be a basis.

Comment: Ah, I see!  Thanks for explaining this so clearly!